# Month field defaults to 00 after update with jquery.ui datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery.ui datepicker ini an ASP.NET MVC app and after getting a date from the database i.e. 2019-12-31 it shows as 2019-00-31

`Editfor` template

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new
{
    @Value = Model.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd"),
    @class = "form-control datepicker text-center"
})
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $.datepicker.formatDate("yy/mm/dd", new Date(1900, 1 - 1, 1));

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
        buttonText: "Calendar"
    });
```

When the page is first rendered it will show the date with correct year and day but 00 for the month. If you change it and save it the save will work but the page will again render a 00 for the month. If you don't change it the date field is change to null and throws and error. I'm guessing this is a formatting error but pretty sure I have what the examples have.

All help is appreciated.

**Edit - this fixed it**

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new
{
    @Value = Model.ToString(), //removed formatting here
    @class = "form-control datepicker text-center"
})
```

and

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $.datepicker.formatDate("yy/mm/dd");

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
        buttonText: "Calendar"
    });
```

Comment: tried something else and solved it myself - edits above

Answer (score 0):

For those that might run across this in the future, consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
    buttonText: "Calendar"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new
{
    @Value = Model.ToString(), //removed formatting here
    @class = "form-control datepicker text-center"
})
-->
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control datepicker text-center" />
```

There is nothing wrong with setting defaults if you have a very large number of entries and you might make minor changes to small amount of them. For one entry, I would advise the above. This initializes the datepicker with the options needed.

See More: [Datepicker Widget | jQuery UI Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)